# Append collected data with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 different data they *load based on each other id* what I try to do is to append my results as row `bootstrap 3 based` something like:

[image: screenone]

> So far I can get 3 sort of my data successfully, **all the problem I
>   have and need help with is how to append data as described in image above?**

## code

`javascript`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(result) {
          $.each(result, function(key, value1) {

            // second data
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('admin/findsubspecification') }}/'+value1['id'],
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('div#dataaa').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4" id="dataparent">'+value1.title+'</div><div class="col-md-8" id="datainfo">'+value.title+'</div></div>');
                });
              }
            });
            // second data

          });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('div#dataaa').append('select set');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

`html`

```
<div id="dataaa"></div>
```

This is how I'm getting my data now:

[image: screentwo]

## Update

Well I have made it work so far. Remained one issue, and that is I cannot get all my data I only can get my first result.

[image: screenthree]

### Changed code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(result) {
          $.each(result, function(key1, value1) {

            // second data
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('admin/findsubspecification') }}/'+value1['id'],
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {

                    // Collect data as option
                    var helpers = '';
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                      helpers = '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
                    });

                    var my_row = $('<div class="row">');
                    var my_html = '<div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-8"><select class="form-control" id="subs" name="subs[]">'+helpers+'</select></div>';
                    my_row.html(my_html);
                    $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
              }
            });
            // second data

          });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('div#dataaa').append('select set');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

## Update 2

As requested here is my first select option code

```
{{ Form::label('selectset', 'Select Set') }}
<select class="form-control" id="selectset" name="selectset">
  <option value="">Select</option>
   @foreach($selectsets as $selectset)
     <option value="{{ $selectset->id }}">{{ $selectset->title }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Without the html we cant figure out how your javascript relate. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski I already did `<div id="dataaa"></div>`

Comment: I think there would be a element like "<select name="selectset></select>" ? as your javascript  suggest. And you will have 2 <select> right?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski oh that one :) that as it is working to return data i didn't share but if you need it wait i'll update again...

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski updated bro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    helpers = '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
});
```

to

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    helpers += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
});
```

because on each iteration, it overwrite its previous result

Comment: :-D appreciate your help.

Comment: actually you can utilize the html-attributes syntax when creating element. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4qzga5kj/6/. It helps you to handle html syntax and you dont have deal with string concatenation, character escape etc.